# Display image without gradient on static card in Glass GDK

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

When I make a static card with a FULL image layout, it looks like there's a shading gradient that fades from dark to clear from bottom to top. This is great for cards that have text, but if I don't have text, I'd like to see the image without modification.

```
Card card = new Card(this);
card.setImageLayout(Card.ImageLayout.FULL);
card.addImage(R.drawable.full_wiring);        
mViews.add(card.toView());
```

I'm interested if there's a way to specify this with Cards. I know I could make a regular android view as an alternative.

Comment: I came across this same issue, and got around it with a custom view just consisting of an `ImageView` as I couldn't find a way to do it with cards, which is a shame as I agree without text the gradient is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

The latest update seems to have killed static cards.  However the XE16 GDK has the new authentication features (https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/authentication) these will let you put a static card in via the Mirror api.  These can have HTML and css elements to do the gradients or other items as you see fit.

Comment: I read the release notes and as you mentioned here, it says static card support has been removed. But i can still use the Card class which essentially creates static cards. What does this mean ?

Comment: Wait... Static cards are going to be killed?